# VM Instances on Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created a VM instances on Google cloud and i want to access it from WAN. I try type address in address bar but it say server down. I can remote desktop to my window instance but cannot access it in browser.

What is the problems? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access linux instances with SSH and windows instances using remote desktop. More details can be found in the google cloud documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance).

**Update:**

If you want to enable http access to your website then you need to

1) Make sure you are trying to connect to correct external ip address. Your server will either have a static or Ephemeral ip address. Ephemeral ip address changes every time you reboot your server. Static ip doesn't change, but it is not free. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#externaladdresses).

2) Make sure you enabled http access in your firewall settings. (Maybe you forgot to check this option when you are creating your virtual machine?) To set the firewall settings go to `Networking -> vpc network -> firewall rules`

[image]

Comment: I can remote desktop to my window instance but cannot access it in browser.

Comment: are you running a web server?

Comment: I"m using Apache tomcat as web server to host application.

Comment: I"m hosting dvwa application. How to allow connection from outside world to my web server.

Comment: I have disable firewall in Windows vm. How to allow http or https connection from internet to my vm?

Comment: go to networking -> vpc network -> firewall rules in google cloud console